# Django ORM order by expression

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Hi i could order by < 2 in ORM
my only idea is:

```
players = GamePlayer.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM `Farmer_gameplayer` WHERE (`Farmer_gameplayer`.`game_id` = %d) ORDER BY `turn` < %d' % (game.pk, game.turn))
```

I'd like to order this:

```
players = GamePlayer.objects.filter(game=game) ORDER BY `turn` < 2
```

Comment: It's perfectly ok to drop to raw sql when you need to do something more esoteric than the orm can handle easily..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>**Note:** You can probably adapt your application to use `ORDER BY turn`, as *qualitatively* the result set isn't very different from `ORDER by turn < 2`. You'll see a difference only in that `ORDER BY turn` would alter the sort of all rows depending on their `turn` column, while `ORDER BY turn < 2` sorts by the boolean expression `turn < 2` which won't reorder all rows beyond that.
Below I present how you can order a Django queryset using an expression, e.g. `turn < 2`</sub>

**Annotate with an expression, then order by it:**

The idea is to annotate a field called `turn_is_less_than_2` that goes [either True or False](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/), then order by it. The said annotation will be representing the expression `turn < 2` that you want to order by later on (`ORDER BY turn < 2`)

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, BooleanField

GamePlayer.objects.filter(game=game).annotate(turn_is_less_than_2=Case(
    When(turn__lt=2, then=True),
    default=False,
    output_field=BooleanField()
)).order_by('turn_is_less_than_2') 

# or order_by('-turn_is_less_than_2') for DESC order instead of ASC
```

Breaking it down to explain:

First I'm just taking your query

```
GamePlayer.objects.filter(game=game)
```

Then what I do is annotate it with a field `turn_is_less_than_2` that is `True` if `turn < 2`, and `False` otherwise

```
GamePlayer.objects.filter(game=game).annotate(turn_is_less_than_2=...)
```

Then when we have annotated that filtered queryset, we can now order_by that field:

```
GamePlayer.objects.filter(game=game).annotate(...).order_by('turn_is_less_than_2')
```

Comment: What if it's a related object you're doing the filtering on?

Comment: @Rollo It should be same, if you don't need expressions you can use the `__` (double underscore) notation in Django to follow relationships, e.g. `order_by('author__age')`. Or if you need expressions you can use that in the `When()` e.g. `When(author__age__lt=40, then=True)`

Comment: It seemed to do this inner join which duplicated loads of objects. I'll try and reproduce and see if it's a bug.

Comment: Is it possible to adapt an expression defined on "self" in a related model programmatically?